# Unable to deploy pgadmin on a RKE2 Kubernetes cluster

Tags: python, linux, kubernetes, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I want to deploy `pgadmin` on a RKE2 Kubernetes cluster to access databases. Unfortunately the `pgadmin` pod crashes due to PSP issues I think. I know PSP is deprecated and we're planning to switch to OPA soon, but it would be efficient to use `pgadmin` in the meantime.

The deployment file looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pgadmin
spec:
  selector:
   matchLabels:
    app: pgadmin
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pgadmin
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: pgadmin4
          image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
          env:
           - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL
             value: "test@ind.nl"
           - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD
             value: "test"
           - name: PGADMIN_PORT
             value: "80"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: pgadminport
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
            runAsGroup: 0
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pgadmin
  labels:
    app: pgadmin
spec:
  selector:
   app: pgadmin
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - port: 80
     nodePort: 30200
```

It returns logs with permission issues:

```
/entrypoint.sh: line 62: /venv/bin/python3: Operation not permitted
sudo: PERM_SUDOERS: setresuid(-1, 1, -1): Operation not permitted
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit
/entrypoint.sh: line 84: /venv/bin/python3: Operation not permitted
/entrypoint.sh: exec: line 92: /venv/bin/gunicorn: Operation not permitted
```

When I edit the `runAsUser` and `runAsGroup` variable to 5050, it returns these logs:

```
/entrypoint.sh: line 62: /venv/bin/python3: Operation not permitted
sudo: unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit
/entrypoint.sh: line 84: /venv/bin/python3: Operation not permitted
/entrypoint.sh: exec: line 92: /venv/bin/gunicorn: Operation not permitted
```

When I edit the `runAsGroup` variable back to 0, it returns these logs:

```
/entrypoint.sh: line 62: /venv/bin/python3: Operation not permitted
sudo: PERM_SUDOERS: setresuid(-1, 1, -1): Operation not permitted
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [5050, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit
/entrypoint.sh: line 84: /venv/bin/python3: Operation not permitted
/entrypoint.sh: exec: line 92: /venv/bin/gunicorn: Operation not permitted
```

UPDATE 1:
The PSP that's being used looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  annotations:
    psp.rke2.io/global-restricted: resolved
  creationTimestamp: "2022-06-30T14:00:25Z"
  name: global-restricted-psp
  resourceVersion: "3493795"
  uid: b7209f38-9609-4b81-b3ef-ab7a17b39bbd
spec:
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
  fsGroup:
    ranges:
    - max: 65535
      min: 0
    rule: MustRunAs
  requiredDropCapabilities:
  - ALL
  runAsUser:
    rule: RunAsAny
  seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny
  supplementalGroups:
    ranges:
    - max: 65535
      min: 0
    rule: MustRunAs
  volumes:
  - configMap
  - emptyDir
  - projected
  - secret
  - downwardAPI
  - persistentVolumeClaim
```

Anybody ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're misssing here is the configuration to handle persistent-data. I tried the same deployment file as yours and just added the `volumes` & `volumeMounts` config, albeit an emptyDir (you might want to persist data though), and it works.

I then use the command

```
kubectl port-forward pgadmin-6ff557759c-m5cxn 8080:80
```

to be able to access the pg-admin console locally on `http://127.0.0.1:8080`.

Here's the deployment.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pgadmin
spec:
  selector:
   matchLabels:
    app: pgadmin
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pgadmin
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: pgadmin4
          image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
          env:
           - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL
             value: "test@ind.nl"
           - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD
             value: "test"
           - name: PGADMIN_PORT
             value: "80"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: pgadminport
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 5050
            runAsGroup: 5050
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/lib/pgadmin
            name: pgadmin-data
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: pgadmin-data
```

Well, I also changed the `runAsUser` & `runAsGroup` to 5050 (taking some inspiration from the helm chart here: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/runix/pgadmin4 (it may not be needed though).

Having said that, it'd be a lot easier for you to use a helm-chart as it allows you easily handle config to add `PersistentVolume` via an existing `PersistentVolumeClaim` or a `storageClass`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @lucas does this solution work for you? If yes, please mark it as accepted. If no, please share more details.

Comment: I'm working from Tuesday till Friday. Unfortunately I'm getting the same error in the logs: Operation not permitted. I think really it's a PSP issue. I will update my post with the PSP configuration